# getting Google Maps API debug key with windows command prompt

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my first time getting a Google Maps API debug key for my Android app. In my Windows command prompt I keep getting "keytool not recognized...." at the prompt `C:\Users\MyName>`. The path to the debug.keystore is `C:\Users\MyName\.android\debug.keystore` I still get the error when I change the directory to `C:\Users\MyName\.android>` is `keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\MyName\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android` the correct command to get the debug key? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get map key as  if you are using jdk1.7

```
    C:\<YOUR_JDK_PATH\bin>keytool -v androiddebugkey -keystore "C:Users\YOUR_NAME\.android
\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

see below image for more help:

[image]

Comment: if you are using jdk1.6 then just remove `-v` from string

Comment: Thank you! Pointing the command prompt to the jdk (1.7.0 in my case) did it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to either add keytool to your PATH variable or say "C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxxx\bin\keytool" instead of just keytool (don't copy and paste that, replace it with the path to your keytool)