# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display a map in my application. I am using this code

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

//get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

//create a criteria object to retrieve provider
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

//get the name of the best provider
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

//get current location
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

//set map type
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

//get latitude and longitude of the current location
double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

//create LatLng object for the current location
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

//show the current location in Google Map
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
//zoom in the Google Map
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
```

and it is working, it displays it, it displays the polygons I created on it, everything works. But in the logcat, I'm always getting this error:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Anyone knows what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason to get this error is if you have updated your eclipse then your API key would have changed.

To get SHA1 fingerprint you have to follow this link,
[[getting Google Maps API debug key with windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146512/getting-google-maps-api-debug-key-with-windows-command-prompt])

From SHA1 fingerprint you can get API key from Google Console site.
[http://www.technicaladvices.com/2012/03/19/generating-keys-for-google-maps-api-using-the-apis-console/]

Paste that API key in manifest file

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your api key" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not replying, I'm out of town, so I'll try this as soon as I am on my computer.

Comment: @grayFox16 did u got it?

Comment: @Naveen I have tried this solution, but the problem still exist. It is probably due to the update for ADT and SDK to the latest version and this problem existed for my case

Comment: @Jiazzy this is basic steps you have to follow. Best thing to do is keep a back up of your code, just use new adt bundle and it would definitely work like charm. That is what worked for me after trying all different things.

Comment: well I have tried changing the api key (I was also changing the name of the application so I had to do that) and the error is not showing anymore. So I will mark this as a correct answer

Comment: I'm facing an app crash with the above log. I have separate map keys for releasing to play and for debugging. With both keys this issue is persisting. The crazy thing is that this error occurs only when i changed my app url from http to https which is not related to this map viewing.