# com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am having

```
Could not find class `'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a'`
```

problem in my Google maps in android. Can anyone help me please, I am stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575631/could-not-find-class-com-google-android-gms-location-internal-parcelablegeofenc

Comment: Me too having same issue any solution is much helpfull..

Comment: I m confirm this is not the issue Martin there must be other problem. @shylendra did  u find any solution.

Comment: @SomirSaikia Yes you are right this is the problem occurring recently. Still not found solution, If so I'll let you know..

Comment: Same issue...Posted My question Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080379/could-not-find-class-com-google-android-gms-location-internal-parcelablegeofenc

Comment: @shylendra I have fixed my issue but do not know if the solution is correct solution or not for you guys. Did you managed to fix the issue? I will post my solution on the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a SHA1 : for my play store app. The key that I generated for google map was a debug key. Next I found that the app once uploaded on the app store and generated a google map key. Google uses some kind of authentication for my app to check whether my map API key is correct or not for my app package. So I used my gmail account from which I have access for uploading app on play store. Next went to Google MAP API console created a key with my SHA1;package name on console. I used this key for my map now.

I think when we are debugging a app which is already on play store this error come because of authentication issue os the map API

for debuging generate another key and for uploading another key or ( API key which was created earlier for the package or app).

This helped me. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: can you give me your log cat